# Inject bytecode using asm before every call to a particular method

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation

How can I rewrite a class (preferably using asm) such that a `setupSpecial()` invocation is introduced before every single call to `special(int)`?

```java
public class Application {

    public void f() {
         System.out.println("A");
         // setupSpecial(); ← to be added
         special(1);
         System.out.println("B");
         // setupSpecial(); ← to be added
         special(2);
         System.out.println("C");
         // setupSpecial(); ← to be added
         special(3);
    }

}
```

Note that both `special()` and `setupSpecial()` are not members of `Application`.

I can pass a `ClassVisitor`+`MethodVisitor` combination and intercept calls to `special(int)` via overriding `visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "com/acme/Magic", "special", "()V", false)`, though this will be too late since the method argument of type integer is already passed via `visitIntInsn(Opcodes.BIPUSH, int)`. I need a way to say *"Now I see the call to `special()`! Roll this call back, turn magic on, and proceed again."*

Comment: Can't you use a proxy ? https://www.mscharhag.com/java/dynamic-proxy-pattern

Example of implementation : https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies

Comment: @cerdoc, I want to capture the source location of the call-site as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72437386/1278899), hence I need to inject the code to the call site. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM has a stack-based architecture, so you don't need to worry about the parameters to the `special(int)` call. If you simply prepend the `setupSpecial()` call to the `special(int)` call using:

```java
@Override
public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {
    if ("com/example/Magic".equals(owner) && "special".equals(name)) {
        visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/example/Magic", "setupSpecial",
                Type.getMethodDescriptor(Type.VOID_TYPE), false);
    }
    super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
}
```

(I assume both `special` and `setupSpecial` to be static, but it does not matter), you'll obtain bytecode similar to this:

```
0: getstatic     #24                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
3: ldc           #30                 // String A
5: invokevirtual #32                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
8: iconst_1
9: invokestatic  #68                 // Method setupSpecial:()V
12: invokestatic #38                 // Method special:(I)V
```

As you can see, the parameter to the `special(int)` call is pushed on the stack **before** the call to `setupSpecial()`, which is unusual. However it will still be at the top of the stack once `setupSpecial()` has finished, so everything will work just fine as long as `setupSpecial()` does not return any value.

If it does, you'll need to add a `pop/pop2` opcode to remove it from the stack.

Comment: This constellation isn’t that unusual. When you have something like `first(a, second(b))`, the first argument to `first` (`a`) is pushed before the call to `second`. So only the fact that `setupSpecial` is `void` and hence, doesn’t produce an argument to `special`, is a bit unusual.